# Converting String to Date using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am taking a String input from user , which I want to convert into java.util.Date instance and print it into specific manner using `SimpleDateFormat` .It is not printing in the specified manner.

```
try {           Date date1;
            date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse("05/18/05");
            System.out.println(date1);
        } 

        catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format your date before you print it out, otherwise you use `Date`'s default format

```
try {           
   Date date1;
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
   date1 = format.parse("05/18/05");
   System.out.println(format.format(date1));
}
```

When you do

```
System.out.println(date1);
```

internally, the method is calling

```
date1.toString();
```

and prints its result. `Date#toString()` is implemented as follows

```
public String toString() {
    // "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
    BaseCalendar.Date date = normalize();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(28);
    int index = date.getDayOfWeek();
    if (index == gcal.SUNDAY) {
        index = 8;
    }
    convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[index]).append(' ');                        // EEE
    convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[date.getMonth() - 1 + 2 + 7]).append(' ');  // MMM
    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getDayOfMonth(), 2).append(' '); // dd

    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getHours(), 2).append(':');   // HH
    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getMinutes(), 2).append(':'); // mm
    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getSeconds(), 2).append(' '); // ss
    TimeZone zi = date.getZone();
    if (zi != null) {
        sb.append(zi.getDisplayName(date.isDaylightTime(), zi.SHORT, Locale.US)); // zzz
    } else {
        sb.append("GMT");
    }
    sb.append(' ').append(date.getYear());  // yyyy
    return sb.toString();
}
```

which results in the `Date` string you are seeing.

Comment: format method will ultimately produce the String.I need the output in java.util.date along with MM/dd/yy format

Comment: @Sanjana A `Date` doesn't have a format. You have your date in `date1`. You'll need to format it to display it as you want.

Answer (score 2):

> It is not printing in the specified manner.

```
System.out.println(date1); // no format given, using the default format
```

You are not specifying a manner.  The date has a no history of the format it was parsed from.  If you want a format, you need to use SimpleDateFormat.format()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdin = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            SimpleDateFormat sdout = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
            Date date = sdin.parse("2013-05-31");
            System.out.println(sdout.format(date));
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestDate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```